# Even when I have no quotes to escape, it still says I have an unclosed string (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, quotes

I've used the find function to be completely sure that there are no quotes that need to be escaped. The html to be put into my "viewbox" div is entirely single quotes, and I'm surrounding it with double quotes. Not a single exception. When I remove what I'm trying to insert, and replace it with a simple 'test', it works fine, so it doesn't seem to be a library issue, or anything like that. Also, the code itself that I'm trying to insert works when I save it as an html file. I'm almost certain I'm overlooking something. I've tried, searched, and done everything I can think of. Here's the javascript code.

**EDIT:** I put all the lines of code onto one line. It's valid, but instead of rendering a bootstrap carousel, it just displayed all the images at once, one after another.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#aprilissue').click(function () {
$('#viewbox').html(
    "
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-2'>
</div>
<div class='col-md-8'>

<center>
<div id='carousel-example-generic' class='carousel slide' data-interval='false'>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class='carousel-inner'>
    <div class='item active'>
      <img src='img/april/page01.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
<div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page02.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
<div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page03.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page04.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page05.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page06.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page07.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page08.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page09.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page10.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page11.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page12.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page13.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page14.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page15.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page16.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page17.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page18.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page19.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page20.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page21.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      <img src='img/april/page22.jpg' alt='>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class='left carousel-control' href='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide='prev'>
    <span class='icon-prev'></span>
  </a>
  <a class='right carousel-control' href='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide='next'>
    <span class='icon-next'></span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-2'>
</div>
</center>
"
    );
});


//when I remove what's above, the code below works.


$('#mayissue').click(function () {
$('#viewbox').html(
"test2"
    );
});
$('#juneissue').click(function () {
$('#viewbox').html(
"test3"
    );
});
$('#julyissue').click(function () {
$('#viewbox').html(
"test4"
    );
});

    });
```

Comment: Multilines string are not supported in JavaScript.

Comment: your string is invalid as line breaks are not allowed except when escaped

Comment: if you absolutely have to keep the string's line breaks for aesthetics purposes, wrap each line with `" blablabla " +`

Comment: Or just ajax the page fragment in when needed

Comment: @user3774582 you could append a `backslash` at the end of every line and that should fix your issue. Going forward however want to move away from having to deal with long strings like that.

Comment: I put all the lines of code onto one line. It's valid, but instead of rendering a bootstrap carousel, it just displayed all the images at once, one after another.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have multiline strings.

To fix this, use separate strings with concatenation:

```
$('#viewbox').html("<div class='row'>" +
               "<div class='col-md-2'>" +
               "</div>") //... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant have a single string that spans multiple lines like that, to get it to work that way you would have to do something like this

```
 $('#viewbox').html("<div class='row'>" +
"<div class='col-md-2'>" + .....
```

With that said, I will then add.  DO NOT ADD HTML THAT WAY

Use a template, or anything other then what you posted.  A very cheap and easy way it to create the html on the page and use css to mark it as display: none, then refenrce the parent object in JS and pass the outerHtml.

Comment: i do not know if "dynamic html building" means creating huge chunks of html code using js ...

Answer (score 0):

A good way to write a long multiline string is to use the magic backslash  `\` at the end of every line. JS, and you, will be happy:

```
$('#viewbox').html("\
    <div class='row'>\
    <div class='col-md-2'>\
    </div>\
    ................ \
    <div class='col-md-2'>\
    </div>\
    </center>\
");
```

[**CONCEPT JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2VcEG/)